# How do I have values from an array show up in a php string?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two values in an array that I want to have show up in a string variable that I am building. Theses values are dynamic and are subject to change, so I want to be able to build the string straight from the array.  I thought I was on the right track but the values are not showing up.

My Code:

```
$range = "WHERE transdate >= \"{$halfway['startdate']}\" AND transdate <= \"{$halfway['enddate']}\"";
```

The output:

```
WHERE transdate >= "" AND transdate <= ""
```

Comment: i hope you escape your array beforehand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me in php 5.3.5 cli. I haven't modified your string

```
$halfway = array(
    'startdate' => 'somedate',
    'enddate' => 'otherdate'
);

$range = "WHERE transdate >= \"{$halfway['startdate']}\" AND transdate <= \"{$halfway['enddate']}\"";

print $range;
```

Output:

```
WHERE transdate >= "somedate" AND transdate <= "otherdate"
```

Check that `$halfway` actually has data.

Comment: wow...haha. I was building the string before the array. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes in the array element.. I think that would work..

`WHERE transdate >= \"{$halfway[startdate]}\" AND transdate <= \"{$halfway[enddate]}\"`

Comment: According to [my testing](http://www.ideone.com/q9QU1), either should work. Tells me it's something wrong with the `$halfway` object.

Comment: "WHERE transdate >= '$halfway[startdate]' AND transdate <= '$halfway[enddate]'";

How about that?

Comment: Yeah this works too, I was building the string before halfway so the values were not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a framework and not use its ORM?

```
$this->ModelName->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'ModelName.transdate BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
            $halfway['startdate'],
            $halfway['enddate']
         )
    )
));
```